# 'Unable to save stock item' error when trying to save creating or editing a product

Tags: product, catalog

I am running Magento 2.2.2 and recently migrated servers. When I am trying to edit or create a new product now, I have the error 'Unable to save stock item'

This is the first time I am facing this issue. I have tried reindexing, clearing cache but the error is still there.

If anyone can assist.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: run this query insert into `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`website_id`,`stock_name`) values (1,0,'Default'); and try this

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have checked this query and it has the values in already. But it still gives the error.